# appending and removing content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I dont think I am using the .remove correctly because instead of "info about canada" being removed from the div "info", it is stacked on top of "info about russia" instead.

js

```
if (code == 'ca') {
        $('#info').append('<p class="i">info about canada</p>');
    } else if (code == 'ru') {
    $('#info').remove('.i');
        $('#info').append('<p class="i">info about russia</p>');
    }
```

html

```
<div id="info">
<h3>Info</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out...I used .empty instead.

Comment: No need to ever do `.empty()` then `.append()`... Just use `.html()`. I added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to replace the contents of `#info` then don't use `remove`, `empty`, or `append`, just use `html`:

```
$('#info').html('<p class="i">info about russia</p>');
```

Comment: saved me so much potential time, should be accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Their is no need to pass parameters to `remove`..

Just do:

```
$('#info .i').remove();
```

and it will remove the `.i` from the `$('#info')` div